# Bound GridView to fill with Information

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have bound GridView with 6 Information, all information are loaded from an ObjectDataSource Into the GridView with BoundFields.

Now i want to show a 7. Information.
This Information i can only calculate while runtime, so its not a stored data.

How to insert that?

I have done that years ago but i cant remember, I only know I have to use an Row-Event and can edit a Label which is stored in my GridView or something like that.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsRPG" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRPGSForUser"
    TypeName="DAL.RPGDAL">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="UserID" DbType="Guid" Name="userID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="RPGID" ID="gridRPG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsRPG">
    <Columns>
       ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridView smart tag select **Add New Column**, then in Choose a field type select **TemplateField** then in Header text type **Sum** and click **OK**.

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    e.Row.Cells[6].Text = (
        int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text) +
         int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) +
          int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) +
           int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text) +
            int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text) + 
        int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[5].Text)
        ).ToString(); ;
}
```